# [TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to tuple]: How to compare a tuple value to a datetime value using Python & SQLite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using the SQLite3 module within Python and I currently have a table that stores a "date" as datetime. However, whenever I try to retrieve that date from the table and compare it to today's date (e.g. today = datetime.datetime.today()), I get an error that says:

```
if row > today:
```

> TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to tuple"

Here is a snippet of the code that I am having trouble with:

```
for row in con.execute('select time_date as "d [datetime]" from fault_record'):

if row < today:
    print row
```

I am stumped on how to convert the tuple date to a datetime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rows are returned as tuples of columns, even if there's only one column.

Changing

```
for row in con.execute('select time_date as "d [datetime]" from fault_record'):
```

to

```
for date, in con.execute('select time_date as "d [datetime]" from fault_record'):
```

will iterate over the dates, instead of the row tuples.